# Как не выйти за границы массива C#

Tags: c#, массивы

Допустим есть двумерный массив 5х5. Берем центральный элемент [3,3] и в каждом элементе окружающем его (т.е. [2,2] [2,3] ... [4,4]) изменяем значение. Тоже самое делаем  и в этих элементах,значение в которых мы изменили и т. д. Как в этой рекурсивной программе предотвратить выход за границы массива?

Comment: Проверять индексы не вариант?

Comment: Да, сразу же после написания вопроса дошло, что можно так. Спасибо за ответ

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Проверку индексов в двумерном массиве можно выполнить так:

```
int[,] array = new int[5, 7];

var w = array.GetLength(0); // вернет 5
var h = array.GetLength(1); // вернет 7

if (x >= 0 && x < w && y >= 0 && y < h)
{
  // array[x, y]
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
if(i>=0&&i<=array.Length-1)
```